# CakePHP - Setting data retrieved from AJAX call to element

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, element

I'm making a new data entry through AJAX. It consists of the model data and some HABTM data as well. I return all this data as a json object from my controller and I would like to add a
CakePHP view element containing this data to the current view, somewhat what twitter does when you post a tweet.

How can I manage to get the json object, append the element and set the data from the json object to said element? I have a good idea about how to append the element but the data setting I'm not clear about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to use CakePHP views to display the results of the JSON data?

If so, you can do it like this:

In your controller:

```
function my_ajax_action() {

   $data = // whatever method you use to fetch your data
   $this->set(compact('data'));
   $this->layout('ajax');

}
```

Create a view file: my_ajax_action.ctp which outputs the formatted $data array

Use ajax to fetch back the HTML not the JSON <- important bit and insert it into the DOM:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/controller/my_ajax_action',
    success: function (result) {
        $('#myelement').html(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually it was an element I wanted to use. So to do it you use $this->render() action and the rest is the same as you said, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use  `$.getJSON` to get the JSON, and then iterate and set the values on your page.
Very straight forward..

Have a look here
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Yes, I know I can do this but I want to use the conventions of CakePHP to make my work easier, just setting an data array to the element and it displaying properly

Comment: Also I'm not talking about a DOM element, I revised my question, I'm talking about a CakePHP view element